# Error Updating Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I have ruby and gems installed, but when I try to run the update suggested by the ruby on rails download page (http://rubyonrails.org/download) I get an error. Here's what I'm executing from the root of my user directory:

```
gem update rails
```

and the terminal returns:

```
Updating installed gems
Updating rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.3/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a permission error.

To make this work do:

```
sudo gem update rails
```

BUT

I would highly suggest you use rvm.
OSX comes with an older version of ruby and with RVM you can install
1.9.3 without hosing the built in version of ruby.

Comment: No problem please remember to select an answer.

Comment: I recommend the use of rbenv and bundler rather than rvm. rvm works, but is invasive and overkill for most cases. Please see this: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/